# Ordered lists with "start" attribute in iText

Tags: html, itext

In a project of mine, I have a functionality that converts an HTML text into a PDF file. I use iText 2.1.7 for that, more specifically the `HTMLWorker` class. By the way, users can also put ordered lists (`<ol>`) in that, and having them starting with a given index. Like this:

[image]

The corresponding HTML is this:

```
<ol start="4" style="list-style-type: decimal;">
...
</ol>
```

However, iText - during the conversion - skips the `start` attribute, producing a list that starts from 1:

[image]

Is there a way to maintain that attribute, and producing the same result in the final PDF? Thank you for any insight.

Comment: I couldn't ended up with a definitive solution in the environment of mine but, for people having the same problem, converting the `start=n` into n-1 invisible `<li>` does the trick. Look here for an example of what I'm talking about: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52205675/regex-how-to-substitute-a-string-with-n-occurrences-of-a-substring

Answer (score 0):

Your problem cannot be reproduced with recent versions of iText.

I used the following HTML file (`lists.html`):

```
<body>
<div>
    <ol start="4" style="list-style-type: decimal;">
        <li>Element 1</li>
        <li>Element 2</li>
        <li>Element 2</li>
    </ol>
</div>
</body>
```

Then I used the following Java code with [iText 7.1.2](https://developers.itextpdf.com/itext7/download-and-install-information/Java) and [pdfHTML 2.0.2](https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfHTML).

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter;

public class Lists {
    public static final String SRC = "src/main/resources/html/lists.html";
    public static final String DEST = "target/results/lists.pdf";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("target/results/");
        file.mkdirs();
        new Lists().createPdf(SRC, DEST);
    }

    public void createPdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException {
        HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new File(src), new File(dest));
    }
}
```

The resulting PDF (`lists.pdf`) looks like this:

[image]

You indicate that you are using iText 2.1.7. That version dates from 2009 and the old `HTMLWorker` functionality has been abandoned many years ago because it was broken beyond repair. Please consult the introduction of the [official HTML to PDF tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml) for an overview of the history of HTML to PDF conversion with iText.

Comment: Thanks for your try. I'm using itext-2.1.7.jar; probably that's the issue, and I simply need to upgrade it.

Comment: OK @Andrea ジーティーオー, please note that [iText 2.1.7 should no longer be used](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/versions-older-than-5). I've updated your question and I've removed my down-vote. I'll close it by referring to a previous Stack Overflow that explains that `HTMLWorker` has been discontinued many years ago.